# What is a single word alternative to "whispered"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word alternative to "whispered". I am already using whispering for emotional, scared or caring dialogue and so the odd time when I try to use it for a neutral (unaffected) whisper it still feels to me like the character is being emotional, scarred or caring which gives of the wrong vibe. The closest I have found is "murmur" but that (to me at least) feels too much like "mumble", and "hiss" is usually used for aggressive whispering. Any suggestions at all?

I could go with something like "he/she said softly/gently/quietly etc" but I'm hoping there's a better alternative?

Comment: Murmuring can mean something indistinct, but can also mean something in a low voice as in this context, so it would be fine to use. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/murmur

Comment: "He/she murmured" is fine, in context it will have the *in a low voice* meaning.

Comment: @Stuart F it looks like this is the answer, please convert your comment and I will accept it. Apologies nnnnnn, Stuart got in first :)

Comment: @FrontEnd This is most common meaning of murmur, which is what I'd tend to assume: 
1 : a half-suppressed or muttered complaint : grumbling

Comment: *Whisper* used in dialog conveys an intent to communicate, whereas *murmur* does not, at least to me.

Answer (score 1):

You're going the wrong way about it.

**Use *whisper* for the neutral whispering**—like you just did in your own explanation of what you were asking about—where the most important thing is only the volume of the voice.

Use any of a myriad of other verbs—*hiss* (anger), *gasp* (shock or fear), *murmur* & *mutter* (uncertain), *sigh* (exhaustion or caring), *purr* (arousal), *breathe* & *pant* (fear), &c. &c. &c.—to add nuance as needed in places where that shading is more important. Even with words like *confide* that don't technically involve loudness, some delicacy is implicit in the idea. Where necessary, you can use adverbs for their volume or just add more context: *He leaned in and...* *He felt her warm breath against his neck as she...* *Making sure El Guapo could not hear, they...*

Answer (score 0):

I know that you were looking for a single word but I honestly think that you could try, "said in a hushed/quiet tone," It doesn't seem to have any certain connotation to it or you can try, "She/He/They breathed," but I'm only in high school so you don't have to trust me; I love writing stories and I'm writing one right now, I've used multiple "unique words" (according to Grammarly) just because I was getting tired of using "I said" a thousand times. I really hope that helped!  If it did, comment and let me know!

Comment: Definitely an option but as mentioned I was hoping for a single word equivalent

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the eternal "He said - she said" I will go with phrases such as "She added quietly (blah blah)." or "(blah blah blah), he offered reluctantly."